# How can I output a blank line from a batch file on the Atari Portfolio?

Tags: ms-dos, atari

I'm am trying to make a batch script on the Atari Portfolio which uses DIP DOS 2.11 (pretty similar to MS-DOS 2.11). I need to put a blank line in my file and it won't work. I have tried `echo.`, `echo/`, `echo(`, `echo[`, `echo]`, `echo+`, and `echo:` When I put for example `echo/` in there it just outputs a `/` on that line. Also `ECHO` , `ECHO <tab>`, double spaces etc. does not work. It just says `ECHO is off`. I guess that shows a difference between DIP DOS and MS-DOS 2.11. Any ideas?

Comment: Tried `echo:` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I’ll add that.

Comment: In that case, I guess there is no other way than typing a file with a single CRLF :) But serious, why wasting a whole line of the little screen space of a Portfolio?

Comment: CLRF? Huh? I made the program in the Terminator 2 ATM hack: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=yB82FNPoiPM. It needs the blank lines still though.

Comment: CRLF is what an empty line in DOS consists of. Also, if you already made it for the movie, why ask again?

Answer (score 9):

In theory, to output a blank line in MS-DOS 2.*x*, you need to add a single space after `ECHO`: `ECHO` .

This doesn’t work in later versions; there, the documented solution is `ECHO` followed by a space and then the character obtained by holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>5</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> on the numeric keypad. This character is a non-breaking space: `ECHO`  . (This should also work in MS-DOS 2.*x*.)

The curious can check [page 759 of *The MS-DOS Encyclopedia*](https://archive.org/details/The_MS-DOS_Encyclopedia_Ray_Duncan/page/759/).

If that doesn’t work, create a file containing a single line, and `TYPE` that:

```
COPY CON BLANK.TXT
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, and in your batch file, use

```
TYPE BLANK.TXT
```

to produce a blank line.

Comment: A Firefox bug I learned of today: <https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359303>. Sigh.

Comment: Yes, I ran into that too :-(.

Comment: Also, The MS-DOS Encyclopedia is available online: <https://www.pcjs.org/documents/books/mspl13/msdos/encyclopedia/section3/>. Can’t link to individual entries, though.

Comment: It’s even available on the IA ;-).

Comment: @user3840170 Wait, that bug is still there? Awesome. I mean, I can see a point, but then again, it's, if at all, only valid for a very narrow use case.

Comment: Oh sorry for not replying in a while. I forgot to add that `ECHO `, `ECHO <tab>`, double spaces etc. does not work. It just says `ECHO is off`. I said DIP DOS 2.11 is similar to MS DOS 2.11, but I guess that shows something that is not the same.

Comment: @Anston even with a non-breaking space?

Comment: @Anston see the update.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. I have been really busy. I typed copy con blank.txt and saved it as a batch file. When I ran it, it messed up the portfolio. When I try to do anything it says "memory full".

Comment: @Anston that’s rather surprising. How did you run it? That’s not what it was intended for – the idea was to display it (`TYPE BLANK.TXT`).

Comment: I guess I should've asked for clarification. What I did was made a batch file with "copy con   blank.txt". What did you mean by "copy con blank.txt"?

Comment: I meant exactly what I wrote: create a file (which isn’t a batch file) using `COPY CON`, and then display it (not run it) using `TYPE`.